# Display sorted list based on tuples and loop in dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting, tuples

I am working on a Coursera python exercise and here is the question

> Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.>
>
> ```
> From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
> ```
>
> Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by hour as shown below.

The link containing the text file is: http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt

The desired output is as the following:

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

This is my code:

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
count = dict()
lst = list()

for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        word = line.split()
        temp = word[5]
        time= temp.split(':')
        hour = time[0]
        count[hour] = count.get(hour, 0) + 1
    
for k, v in count.items():
    lst.append((k, v))

print lst.sort()
```

However, the result I got is None. When I changed the last line into:

```
print lst
```

The result became:

```
[('11', 6), ('10', 3), ('15', 2), ('14', 1), ('04', 3), ('16', 4), ('19', 1), ('18', 1), ('09', 2), ('17', 2), ('06', 1), ('07', 1)]
```

I googled and find one solution to this question which is like this:

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    wds = line.split()
    if len(wds) < 5 : continue
    if wds[0] != "From" : continue
    when = wds[5]
    tics = when.split(":")
    if len(tics) != 3 : continue
    hour = tics[0]
    counts[hour] = counts.get(hour,0) + 1
lst = counts.items()
lst.sort()
for key, val in lst :
    print key, val
```

Aside from the loop iterating lines in the text file, I did not see functional difference between my incorrect code and the correct code I got from github.

Could anyone give me some insights here?

Comment: One of your issues was that you did `print lst.sort()`. `lst.sort` returns `None`. In your original code, try replacing that with `print sorted(lst)`, or `lst.sort()` and then `print lst`

Comment: `list.sort()` doesn't return value but just sorts the list in place. If you want to create new list that is sorted user `sorted` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), calling `lst.sort()` will sort a list in place. This means that it directly modifies the list. What you want to use is [`sorted(lst)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), which will return a sorted list.

Or, as pointed out in the comments, call

```
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

to get your desired output.